# How to redirect to two different pages in radgrid using two command buttons inside radgrid?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, telerik, radgrid

I have a radgrid1 and inside radgrid Item template i have two asp.net imagebutton namely imagebutton1 and imagebutton2 ....

i want when i click on Selected radgrid Item whose id is id then after clicking on Image Button1 i redirect to ~/book.aspx?id=1

and if i click on imagebutton2 then i redirect to ~/details.aspx?id=1

Note : the id of the item will be changed dynamically according to the selected radgrid row .

I have already done it using simple Gridview but m unable to perform this action using radgrid.

Help me please guys...!

Comment: Can you provide some code? (the current RadGrid or the old GridView)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code snippet.

.aspx

```
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id"
            >
            <Columns>

                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton  ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"  CommandName="BookPage"/>
                        <asp:ImageButton  ID="ImageButton2" runat="server"  CommandName="DetailPage"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>


            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
```

.asp.cs

```
  protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;

    string strId = item.GetDataKeyValue("Id").ToString();

    if (e.CommandName == "BookPage")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/book.aspx?id=" + strId);
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "DetailPage")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/details.aspx?id=" + strId);
    }
```

}